# Combine two smartdiagram diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, smartdiagram

I would like to join up two [smartdiagram](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram) `circular diagrams`, so that there is only one `Research` node. So far I have got:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\smartdiagramset{
uniform color list=white!90!gray for 4 items,
uniform arrow color=true,
}
\smartdiagram[circular diagram:clockwise]{Sleeping,Eating,Research,Eating}
\smartdiagram[circular diagram]{Research, Finding problem,Solving problem,
                                Writing up solution}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

which (obviously) gives me the following:

[image: MWE executed]

Is it possible to do this with smartdiagrams, or do I have to revert to full tikz?

Comment: In meanwhile when you waiting for better solution try the following dirty trick: between smart diagrams put `\vskip-3em\hskip-6pt`

Comment: Nice... I suppose this would make it a proper MWE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there doesn't seem to be a quick an easy answer, I have just gone back to TikZ and recreated the drawing there. I am so slow with TikZ still!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]  
\tikzset{
    mynode/.style={rectangle,rounded corners, draw=gray, top color=white,
                   bottom color=white!90!gray,very thick, inner sep=1em,
                   minimum size=1em, text centered, minimum width=2cm, 
                   drop shadow, text width=1.75cm},
    myright/.style={-{Stealth[length=4mm]}, color=gray, line width=0.1cm,
                   draw, shorten <=0.3cm,shorten >=0.3cm, bend right},
    myleft/.style={-{Stealth[length=4mm]}, color=gray, line width=0.1cm, 
                   draw, shorten <=0.3cm,shorten >=0.3cm, bend left},
}

\node[mynode] (research) {Research};
\node[mynode] at ([yshift=-2.75cm] 0:2.75cm) (writing) {Writing up solution};
\node[mynode] at ([yshift=-2.75cm] 180:2.75cm) (finding) {Finding problem};
\node[mynode] at ([yshift=-2.75cm] 270:2.75cm) (solving) {Solving problem};
\node[mynode] at ([yshift=2.75cm] 0:2.75cm) (eating1) {Eating};
\node[mynode] at ([yshift=2.75cm] 90:2.75cm) (sleeping) {Sleeping};
\node[mynode] at ([yshift=2.75cm] 180:2.75cm) (eating2) {Eating};

\path[myright] (research) to (finding);
\path[myright] (finding) to (solving);
\path[myright] (solving) to (writing);
\path[myright] (writing) to (research);
\path[myleft] (research) to (eating2);
\path[myleft] (eating2) to (sleeping);
\path[myleft] (sleeping) to (eating1);
\path[myleft] (eating1) to (research);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

This gives me:

[image: Solution Picture]

Of course it's much more verbose, but also more versatile (I can for example now easily add text to the arrows). If you can think of improvements, please comment!